# Maximizing the number of nodes in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph has at most $e$ edges per node and the shortest distance between any two nodes is at most $d$, what is the maximum number of nodes $(M)$ this graph can have.

For example:
If $(e,d) = (2,6)$ then $M = 13$ because a ring of $13$ nodes each attached to two neighboring nodes would have a maximum distance of $6$ between any two nodes.

Here are the easy cases:

if $e = 1$ then $M = 2$

if $e = 2$ then $M = 2d+1$

if $d = 1$ then $M = e+1$

Also, I suspect that if $(e,d) = (3,2)$ then $M = 8$

Answer (score 3):

This is the [degree diameter problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_diameter_problem).  There is a known bound on the number of vertices (the [Moore bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_bound)).  There are very few graphs that actually attain this bound for specific values of the diameter, your $d$, and degree, your $e$.  The Moore bound is  $M_{2,d} = 2d+1$ and, for $e>2$, $M_{e,d} = 1+e \frac{(e-1)^d-1}{e-2}$.

The current state of the art (maximal graphs with given degree and diameter) is summarized [here](http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree_Diameter_Problem_for_General_Graphs).  As I write this, diameter $= 2$ is well studied, after that, degree $\leq 16$ is well studied with degree $=2$ very well studied.  After that, diameter $\leq 6$ is well studied and thereis much detailed knowledge for degree $\leq 16$ and diameter $\leq 4$.  We have complete knowledge for diameter $=2$ and degree $\leq 7$ and for diameter $=3$ and degree $\leq 4$.  For other diameter/degree pairs, there is a gap between vertex counts of explicitly constructed graphs and the provable maximum.